# Find in project window appearing blank in XCode Version 3.2.5

Tags: xcode, ios4, xcode3.2

I have messed up with some of the settings in my XCode project and now when ever I try to find a text in project the finder window is coming as blank. I have quit my XCode and restarted my Mac multiple times but still this problem persists. This behavior is quite weird as it is happening only in a particular project and in rest of the project it is working fine. Please see the screen shot for the reference. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem being related to one project only, might be related to project settings :

You should try moving / deleting these files : `YourProject.xcodeproj/<USERNAME>.*`

*(if I remember well, `.pbxuser` / `.perspectivev3` files keeps tracks of stuff like opened files... and windows sizes...)*

Comment: Thanks for giving me the right direction Vincent, after deleting .pbxuser and .mode1v3 my problem got resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Close Xcode completely and in your project folder,

1. Right-click on 'projectname.xcodeproj' file.
2. On the drop down menu, select show package contents.
3. Delete 'username.mode1v3' file.

Start Xcode and enjoy.

Reference: http://mindtn.com/FunWithTech/?p=3